# How to load .kv files?

Tags: python, kivy

I started to learn kivy and I also tried to use kivy language, but my program `app.py` did not read my `app.kv` file, so all I get is a blackscreen.
I heard that it is possible to load the the `.kv` file, but I could not find the command.

Comment: Thanks, helpful questation :) Quick solve my issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
Builder.load_file('kivi.kv')
```